# How can configure CAS 4.0 with LDAP ApacheDS

Tags: ssl, ldap, ssl-certificate, cas, apacheds

I want to configure CAS server 4.0 with ApacheDS LDAP. I followed the bellow steps:

1- Based on [this Link](http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.0.0/installation/LDAP-Authentication.html) I modify the deployerConfigContext.xml  file. The following beans added to this file:

```
<bean id="ldapAuthenticationHandler"
      class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.LdapAuthenticationHandler"
      p:principalIdAttribute="uid"
      c:authenticator-ref="authenticator">
    <property name="principalAttributeMap">
        <map>
            <!--
               | This map provides a simple attribute resolution mechanism.
               | Keys are LDAP attribute names, values are CAS attribute names.
               | Use this facility instead of a PrincipalResolver if LDAP is
               | the only attribute source.
               -->
            <entry key="member" value="member" />
            <entry key="mail" value="mail" />
            <entry key="displayName" value="displayName" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticator" class="org.ldaptive.auth.Authenticator"
      c:resolver-ref="dnResolver"
      c:handler-ref="authHandler" />

<!--
   | The following DN format works for many directories, but may need to be
   | customized.
   -->
<bean id="dnResolver"
      class="org.ldaptive.auth.FormatDnResolver"
      c:format="uid=%s,${ldap.baseDn}" />

<bean id="authHandler" class="org.ldaptive.auth.PooledBindAuthenticationHandler"
      p:connectionFactory-ref="pooledLdapConnectionFactory" />

<bean id="pooledLdapConnectionFactory"
      class="org.ldaptive.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
      p:connectionPool-ref="connectionPool" />

<bean id="connectionPool"
      class="org.ldaptive.pool.BlockingConnectionPool"
      init-method="initialize"
      p:poolConfig-ref="ldapPoolConfig"
      p:blockWaitTime="${ldap.pool.blockWaitTime}"
      p:validator-ref="searchValidator"
      p:pruneStrategy-ref="pruneStrategy"
      p:connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory" />

<bean id="ldapPoolConfig" class="org.ldaptive.pool.PoolConfig"
      p:minPoolSize="${ldap.pool.minSize}"
      p:maxPoolSize="${ldap.pool.maxSize}"
      p:validateOnCheckOut="${ldap.pool.validateOnCheckout}"
      p:validatePeriodically="${ldap.pool.validatePeriodically}"
      p:validatePeriod="${ldap.pool.validatePeriod}" />

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.ldaptive.DefaultConnectionFactory"
      p:connectionConfig-ref="connectionConfig" />

<bean id="connectionConfig" class="org.ldaptive.ConnectionConfig"
      p:ldapUrl="${ldap.url}"
      p:connectTimeout="${ldap.connectTimeout}"
      p:useStartTLS="${ldap.useStartTLS}"
      p:sslConfig-ref="sslConfig" />

<bean id="sslConfig" class="org.ldaptive.ssl.SslConfig">
    <property name="credentialConfig">
        <bean class="org.ldaptive.ssl.X509CredentialConfig"
              p:trustCertificates="${ldap.trustedCert}" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="pruneStrategy" class="org.ldaptive.pool.IdlePruneStrategy"
      p:prunePeriod="${ldap.pool.prunePeriod}"
      p:idleTime="${ldap.pool.idleTime}" />

<bean id="searchValidator" class="org.ldaptive.pool.SearchValidator" />
```

Also the bellow properties added to the cas.properties:

```
#========================================
# General properties
#========================================
ldap.url=ldaps://localhost:10636



# LDAP connection timeout in milliseconds
ldap.connectTimeout=30000

# Whether to use StartTLS (probably needed if not SSL connection)
ldap.useStartTLS=true

#========================================
# LDAP connection pool configuration
#========================================
ldap.pool.minSize=3
ldap.pool.maxSize=10
ldap.pool.validateOnCheckout=false
ldap.pool.validatePeriodically=true

# Amount of time in milliseconds to block on pool exhausted condition
# before giving up.
ldap.pool.blockWaitTime=3000

# Frequency of connection validation in seconds
# Only applies if validatePeriodically=true
ldap.pool.validatePeriod=3000

# Attempt to prune connections every N seconds
ldap.pool.prunePeriod=3000

# Maximum amount of time an idle connection is allowed to be in
# pool before it is liable to be removed/destroyed
ldap.pool.idleTime=6000

#========================================
# Authentication
#========================================

ldap.baseDn=dc=example,dc=com

# Base DN of users to be authenticated
ldap.authn.baseDn=dc=example,dc=com

# Manager DN for authenticated searches
ldap.authn.managerDN=uid=admin,ou=system

# Manager password for authenticated searches
ldap.authn.managerPassword=secret

# Search filter used for configurations that require searching for DNs
#ldap.authn.searchFilter=(&(uid={user})(accountState=active))
ldap.authn.searchFilter=(uid={0})

# Search filter used for configurations that require searching for DNs
#ldap.authn.format=uid=%s,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=org
ldap.authn.format=uid=%s,ou=system

ldap.trustedCert=file:/D:/ApacheDS.cer
```

Also I used [InstallCert](https://github.com/escline/InstallCert) to add the port of localhosr:8443 (tomcat) and localhost:10636 (ApacheDS) to the cacers file. And with [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) export the ApacheDS.cer from ApacheDs certification from cacers.

My server.xml file of tomcat modified as bellow:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="50" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
               keystoreFile="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_60/jre/lib/security/cacerts" 
               keystorePass="changeit"
               />
```

Also the following Jars add to the apache-tomcat-8.0.8\webapps\cas-server-webapp-4.0.0\WEB-INF\lib :
cas-server-support-ldap-4.0.0.jar
spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-ldap-1.2.1.jar
ldaptive-1.0.5.jar

Finally! After lots of struggling tries I get the bellow error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize pool size
    at org.ldaptive.pool.AbstractConnectionPool.initialize(AbstractConnectionPool.java:258)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: [org.ldaptive.provider.ConnectionException@3778440::resultCode=null, matchedDn=null, responseControls=null, referralURLs=null, messageId=-1, providerException=javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: localhost:10636; socket closed]
    at org.ldaptive.provider.jndi.JndiStartTLSConnectionFactory.createInternal(JndiStartTLSConnectionFactory.java:95)
    at org.ldaptive.provider.jndi.JndiStartTLSConnectionFactory.createInternal(JndiStartTLSConnectionFactory.java:37)
    at org.ldaptive.provider.AbstractProviderConnectionFactory.create(AbstractProviderConnectionFactory.java:99)
    at org.ldaptive.DefaultConnectionFactory$DefaultConnection.open(DefaultConnectionFactory.java:295)
    at org.ldaptive.pool.AbstractConnectionPool.createConnection(AbstractConnectionPool.java:482)
    at org.ldaptive.pool.AbstractConnectionPool.createAvailableConnection(AbstractConnectionPool.java:523)
    at org.ldaptive.pool.AbstractConnectionPool.grow(AbstractConnectionPool.java:363)
    at org.ldaptive.pool.AbstractConnectionPool.initialize(AbstractConnectionPool.java:252)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: localhost:10636; socket closed
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.readReply(Connection.java:454)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.extendedOp(LdapClient.java:1202)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.extendedOperation(LdapCtx.java:3206)
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.extendedOperation(InitialLdapContext.java:183)
    at org.ldaptive.provider.jndi.JndiStartTLSConnectionFactory.startTLS(JndiStartTLSConnectionFactory.java:134)
    at org.ldaptive.provider.jndi.JndiStartTLSConnectionFactory.createInternal(JndiStartTLSConnectionFactory.java:92)
    ... 84 more
```

Could you possibly help me to solve this issue! I really don't know the main reason of my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I can find the solution! Listed bellow are the steps that help you to connect to AacheDS through CAS server 4.

1. Download cas-server-4.0.0-release.zip
2. Download Tomcat 8 and run it
3. Extract the cas-server-4.0.0-release.zip and copy cas-server-webapp-4.0.0.war into apache-tomcat-8.0.8\webapps of your tomcat. Wait till Tomcat extract the War file and make cas-server-webapp-4.0.0
4. Stop Tomcat Server
5. Go to conf folder of your Tomcat and edit the server.xml file. You should uncomment the HTTPS part of this file.

   ```
   <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
          maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
          clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
          keystoreFile="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_60/jre/lib/security/cacerts" 
          keystorePass="changeit"             
          />
   ```
6. As you can see , the certification of HTTPS Tomcat should be added to the cacerts file. You can check the following link to do this:
   [A Simple Step-By-Step Guide To Apache Tomcat SSL Configuration](http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-ssl)
7. Go to the apache-tomcat-8.0.8\webapps\cas-server-webapp-4.0.0\WEB-INF and replace deployerConfigContext.xml content with the following:
   [Go to my Blog to copy the content of file](https://sites.google.com/site/mkoohim/stories/how-can-configure-cas-4-0-with-ldap-apacheds)

[image]

8. Go to the apache-tomcat-8.0.8\webapps\cas-server-webapp-4.0.0\META-INF\maven\org.jasig.cas\cas-server-webapp and add the following to the pom.xml:

[image]

9. Add the following jar files into apache-tomcat-8.0.8\webapps\cas-server-webapp-4.0.0\WEB-INF\lib

   - cas-server-support-ldap-4.0.0.jar
   - spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
   - spring-ldap-1.2.1.jar
   - ldaptive-1.0.5.jar
10. Run ApacheDS
11. Connect to your ApacheDS with Apache Directory Studio and create a user in dc=example,dc=com
    [image: Apache Directory Studio]
12. Start Tomcat
13. Go to the http://localhost:8080/cas-server-webapp-4.0.0/login
14. Type username and password that you made in the Apache Directory Studio. You can login to CAS with ldap user now!

Comment: I think this solution has some problems! I can not delete it! Sorry!

Answer (score 5):

I don`t know is it late to answer or not, but to day I had same problem and after reading the **ldaptive** project source, I found the answer as below:

just add the p:failFastInitialize="false" parameter to your **connectionPool** bean just like

```
<bean id="connectionPool"
      class="org.ldaptive.pool.BlockingConnectionPool"
      init-method="initialize"
      p:poolConfig-ref="ldapPoolConfig"
      p:blockWaitTime="${ldap.pool.blockWaitTime}"
      p:validator-ref="searchValidator"
      p:pruneStrategy-ref="pruneStrategy"
      p:connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory" p:failFastInitialize="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using successfully Moghadam's solution above, but I had to make a small adjustment in **deployerConfigContext.xml**:

```
<bean id="ldapAuthenticationHandler" class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.LdapAuthenticationHandler" >
    <constructor-arg ref="authenticator" />
    <property name="principalAttributeMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="mail" value="mail" />
            <entry key="cn" value="cn" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Please notice I removed the *p:principalIdAttribute="uid"* property.